# Проверка "инициализации" приложения

Tags: vue.js, typescript, nuxt.js

Всем привет(надеюсь я все правильно делаю), решил значит я попробовать себя в вебе, ну и для начала хочу использовать Nuxt3 + ts. Но у меня есть вопрос по реализации одной вещи:

Так вот, есть переменная(определяется при старте приложения) которая определяет, был ли пользователь зарегистрирован ранее. Если был, то открываем главную страницу, а если нет, то страницу "инициализации сайта". Сейчас я реализовал перенаправления через middleware, но правильно ли это? Может это необходимо делать на стороне клиента?? То есть, запрашивать у сервера информацию о приложении и хранить уже эту переменную на фронте(я не уверен, что так стоит делать) :/

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)2. [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Изменил